# Is it possible to create shared preference files in sdcard

Tags: android, preferences

Can anyone help me ? Is it possible to create shared preference files in sdcard rather than on private path of an android application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify where shared preferences are stored.Its a private storage. if you want to use sd card use
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). and get the path of directories stored in sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible by reading&writing the xml file into the external storage ,but it's not the same as sharedPreferences. you will have to implement your own way , or use the android code of this class.
however , there are some disadvantage over using the internal storage:

1. anything you store on the sdcard is visible to every application and the end user can read it by just opening it.
   only in the internal storage you get some sort of protection against reading the file , so that only rooted devices can read the files.
2. external storage can also be unmounted , so the data can sometimes be unreachable. you need to handle possible errors that can occur because of this.
3. uninstalling the app while the sd card is mounted means that the data will stay on the sdcard .